# ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", ds); Line gives an error, Why?

Tags: c#, excel

I want to export my database to an Excel worksheet. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

I tried `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`;

```
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table_2 ;",conDataBase);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            /*  bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
            */

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_DataSet");
            ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            ds.Tables.Add(dbdataset);
            ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", ds);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using SSMS to do this rather than Visual Studio. You can use the Wizard tool within SQL Server to export data to an excel file and you can create an SSIS package if you need to do this on an ongoing basis. See this article for additional info [How to import and Export SQL Server data to an Excel File](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/)

If you really do want to use Interop it may be better to explicitly export each table.

```
//Launch an Excel session
        Application excelapp = new Application();
        excelapp.Visible = true;

        _Workbook workbook = (_Workbook)(excelapp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));
        _Worksheet worksheet = (_Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

        //Create Worksheet Headers
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Order number";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Delivery carrier";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Shipper arrive early";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Shipper city";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Shipper state";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Consignee arrive early";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Consignee city";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Consignee state";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 9] = "BOL";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 10] = "Consignee reference";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Shipper actual arrival";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Shipper actual departure";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 13] = "Status";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 14] = "Consignee actual arrival";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 15] = "Consignee actual departure";

        int row1 = 1;

        //Format text type in excel
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";   

        //Write Data to Each Row of Worksheet
        foreach (DB_DataSet.Row row in report_Data)
        {
            row1++;

            worksheet.Cells[row1, 1] = row.Order_number;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 2] = row.Delivery_Carrier;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 3] = row.Shipper_arrive_early;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 4] = row.Shipper_city;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 5] = row.Shipper_state;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 6] = row.Consignee_arrive_early;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 7] = row.Consignee_city;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 8] = row.Consignee_state;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 9] = row.BOL;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 10] = row.Consignee_reference;
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 11] = row.Shipper_Actual_Arrival;
            try { worksheet.Cells[row1, 12] = row.Shipper_Actual_departure; } catch { }
            try { worksheet.Cells[row1, 13] = row.status; } catch { }
            try { worksheet.Cells[row1, 14] = row.Consignee_actual_arrival; } catch { }
            try { worksheet.Cells[row1, 15] = row.Consignee_actual_departure; } catch { }

            //Format Worksheet
            worksheet.Cells[row1, 15].EntireRow.Font.Name = "Arial";
        }
```

Thank you,

Joseph